# Excel-VBA How to know which dynamically created UserForm TextBox has changed?

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling, excel-2010

I have an excel UserForm that creates textboxes during execution time. code as follows;

```
Dim CompHandler() As New CCompHandler
Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox   
Dim count As Integer
For i in Range(something)
    If i = anotherthing Then
        Set tb = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "tb" & count)
        With tb
            .Width = iTbWidth
            .Top = count * distance
            .Left = iTbLeft
            .Height = iTbHeight
            .Value = Cells(row, column)
            ReDim Preserve CompHandler(0 To count)
            Set CompHandler(count).TextBoxGroup = tb
        End With
    count = count + 1
    End If
Next i
```

I want to write back the changed value to the corresponding cell.
I'm already able to get when the box has changed and the new value with this code on a `class called CCompHandler`:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents TextBoxGroup As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TextBoxGroup_Change()

    MsgBox TextBoxGroup

End Sub
```

So.. any ideas on how can I get which textbox has changed?
Or maybe is there a better way of doing that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is CompHandler defined? Is Componentes the user form? I cannot test or fiddle with this without making ALOT of guesses. Mind giving us the rest of the code?

Comment: @DanielCook: I have made it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tag property is typically used for something like this.  On creation add something like:

```
With tb
  ...
  .Tag = i.Address
...
End With
```

You can then access the Tag property later, with something like:

```
Debug.Print tbWhoseValueHasChanged.Tag
```

Your code snippet has a lot of undefined/unclear variables, including `i`.  I assumed it was a range variable in the above.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I use that inside the class handler? Or is there a better way of using it?

Comment: You said you can get when the TextBox has changed, so just access its Tag property at that time.  It's persistent.  See edit.

Comment: It just worked. Thank you! I feel like it was just a silly question.